# No preset version installed for command virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, asdf

I tried to create a virtual environment for python installed from asdf:

It gave me this error:

```
virtualenv whatsapp-bot                                                                           ─╯
No preset version installed for command virtualenv
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install python 3.10.7

or add one of the following versions in your config file at
python 3.10.4
python 3.9.12
```

I have tried to search for the issue with no solution.

Answer (score 1):

After reading some other related issues, I found the documentation located at:
[Documentation](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/core.html#reshim)

So what was needed was to reshim

```
asdf reshim python
```

That solved it!